# Pandas: Apportioning parent row value to child rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where the parent rows are followed by child rows. Lets say, the parent row has details of a package and the child rows have details of the products in the package.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTWtr.png)

The parent row has a price and the child rows have 0 as price. I want a way in pandas to apportion the price of the parent record to the child records. This can be populated in a new column.

There are different packages so there is no fixed window I can use to solve this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. The ouput I expect is below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJxEY.png)

One way to identify the parent row is it always has the value in column P euqal to the value in column package

Comment: Is the number of child records always 4? Also in the image,  yellow and green colors both have "package 1" as "pack" column.

Comment: No, it depends on the package and can be any number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby` and `transform`

```py
m = df['P'].eq(df['package'])
df['out'] = (df.groupby(m.cumsum())
             ['price'].transform(lambda col: col.item()/(len(col)-1))
             .mask(m, pd.NA))
```

Comment: Hi, this works - I had to use tolist()[0] instead of item() 
 
`df.groupby(m.cumsum())['price'].transform(lambda col: col.tolist()[0]/(len(col)-1)).mask(m, pd.NA)` 

Could you please explain what each part does, so I can understand this better? I already tried prforming it in parts and have a fair understanding but your explanation will help solidify my understanding.

Comment: @KarthikKumarPremkumar Couldn't test it, but if my memory suits me well, `item()` return first item in Series, or you can try `col.iloc[0]`.